# How do I condense all these "if" statements?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and programming in general and I made this program that lets you add days to today's current date and it would output what that date would be. Not very useful, but I got quite annoyed at how much space it was taking and was wondering if it could be made smaller and more condensed, since it's quite simple. I dont actually have a clue. So if someone could show me that would be nice.

```py
import datetime
calendar = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 6:"Friday", 0:"Saturday"}
Day = eval(input("Enter how many days you want to look into the future: "))
todayDate = datetime.date.today()
x = todayDate.strftime("%A")
if x == "Sunday" :
    y = ((1+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
if x == "Monday" :
    y = ((2+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
if x == "Tuesday" :
    y = ((3+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
if x == "Wednesday" :
    y = ((4+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
if x == "Thursday" :
    y = ((5+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
if x == "Friday" :
    y = ((6+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
if x == "Saturday" :
    y = ((7+ Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
```

Comment: Do you want to know what day of the week will be after N days?

Comment: yeah, that's what i wanted to do

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval`, try inputting something like `locals().clear()` rather than the integer you expect

Comment: @Sayse I dont understand what you mean? I shouldn't use 'eval'? Why? What should I do instead?

Comment: enter `locals().clear()` as your user's input and you'll soon find your program crashing, parse the number as an integer instead with `int`

Comment: @slimeworm, what does [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) do? What purpose are you using `eval()` here for anyway?

Comment: @ikkachu I put it there so that everything can stay as an int

Answer (score 2):

```py
offset = {d: o for o, d in calendar.items()}
y = (offset[x] + day) % 7
print(calendar[y])
```

Comment: Or just use timedelta

Comment: @Mur4al Sure, but this is likely an exercise and it gets the point across that 'my approach could be done much better' rather than 'there exists another approach'.

Comment: that is way better than what i wrote. If you dont mind how does the offset thing work?

Comment: @slimeworm `offset` is just a dictionary. Print it. You can see it as the 'inverse' of `calendar`.

Comment: This is a dict comprehension. In this case it was used to create new dictionary with reversed keys and calues from your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timedelta to add any amount of time to a date.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

x=5#or any amount of days you want
date = date.today()
new_date=date+timedelta(days=x)
print(new_date.strftime('%A'))
```

Comment: What would this print at 23:30 on Monday, assuming the clocks go forward by 1 hour due winter/summertime in the night from Monday to Tuesday?

Comment: "Saturday", I think. Date does not have timezone, does it? If one asked, what date would it be five days from now, local timezones could cause a problem. But I'm not that familiar with DST. What's the catch?

Comment: The catch is that "24 hours from now" and "tomorrow" are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't wish to create an inverse dictionary there are multiple things you can do with your own code.

- dont repeat yourself (the printing and exiting can be done after the if statement
- use elif to avoid checking if statements unnecessarily (wouldn't currently happen with seperate exits though)

```
x = todayDate.strftime("%A")
if x == "Sunday" :
    y = ((1+ Day) % 7)
elif x == "Monday" :
    y = ((2+ Day) % 7)
elif x == "Tuesday" :
    y = ((3+ Day) % 7)
elif x == "Wednesday" :
    y = ((4+ Day) % 7)
elif x == "Thursday" :
    y = ((5+ Day) % 7)
elif x == "Friday" :
    y = ((6+ Day) % 7)
elif x == "Saturday" :
    y = ((7+ Day) % 7)
print(calendar[y]) 
exit()
```

Python 3.10 will bring along the [`match` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/) that will make this slightly more efficient

```
x = todayDate.strftime("%A")
match x:
    case "Sunday" :
        y = ((1+ Day) % 7)
    case "Monday" :
        y = ((2+ Day) % 7)
    case "Tuesday" :
        y = ((3+ Day) % 7)
    case "Wednesday" :
        y = ((4+ Day) % 7)
    case "Thursday" :
        y = ((5+ Day) % 7)
    case "Friday" :
        y = ((6+ Day) % 7)
    case "Saturday" :
        y = ((7+ Day) % 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when condensing/deduplicating code the first thing you should do is identify what is it that you're repeating a lot.

On your code, for instance, we see this "structure" many times:

```py
if x == <SOME DAY>:
    y = ((<SOME INTEGER> + Day) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
```

So we'd like to abstract that away, so we only write it once (see [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

So we'd like to write something like this:

```py
def increment_days_and_print(day, increment):
    y = ((day + increment) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()
```

Then we can replace all that repeating code with a call to the function we defined:

```py
def increment_days_and_print(day, increment):
    y = ((day + increment) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()

calendar = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 6:"Friday", 0:"Saturday"}
Day = eval(input("Enter how many days you want to look into the future: "))
todayDate = datetime.date.today()
x = todayDate.strftime("%A")

if x == "Sunday":
    increment_days_and_print(1, Day)
if x == "Monday":
    increment_days_and_print(2, Day)
if x == "Tuesday":
    increment_days_and_print(3, Day)
if x == "Wednesday":
    increment_days_and_print(4, Day)
if x == "Thursday":
    increment_days_and_print(5, Day)
if x == "Friday":
    increment_days_and_print(6, Day)
if x == "Saturday":
    increment_days_and_print(7, Day)
```

That's much better already, isn't it? We could also refactor it like this:

```py
def increment_days_and_print(day, increment):
    y = ((day + increment) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()

calendar = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 6:"Friday", 0:"Saturday"}
Day = eval(input("Enter how many days you want to look into the future: "))
todayDate = datetime.date.today()
x = todayDate.strftime("%A")

if x == "Sunday":
    start = 1
if x == "Monday":
    start = 2
if x == "Tuesday":
    start = 3
if x == "Wednesday":
    start = 4
if x == "Thursday":
    start = 5
if x == "Friday":
    start = 6
if x == "Saturday":
    start = 7

increment_days_and_print(start, Day)
```

Finally, notice that we're essentially setting `start` to a svalue, given a value of `x`. This is exactly what a `dict` is for:

```py
def increment_days_and_print(day, increment):
    y = ((day + increment) % 7)
    print(calendar[y]) 
    exit()

calendar = {1:"Sunday", 2:"Monday", 3:"Tuesday", 4:"Wednesday", 5:"Thursday", 6:"Friday", 0:"Saturday"}
Day = eval(input("Enter how many days you want to look into the future: "))
todayDate = datetime.date.today()
x = todayDate.strftime("%A")

weekday_numbers = {
  "Sunday": 1,
  "Monday": 2,
  "Tuesday": 3,
  "Wednesday": 4,
  "Thursday": 5,
  "Friday": 6,
  "Saturday": 0
}

start = weekday_numbers[x]

increment_days_and_print(start, Day)
```

Finally, doing some cleanup:

```py
weekday_numbers = [
    (1, "Sunday"),
    (2, "Monday"),
    (3, "Tuesday"),
    (4, "Wednesday"),
    (5, "Thursday"),
    (6, "Friday"),
    (0, "Saturday")
]

num_to_weekday = dict((d, w) for (d, w) in weekday_numbers)
weekday_to_num = dict((w, d) for (d, w) in weekday_numbers)

increment = int(input("Enter how many days you want to look into the future: "))
today = datetime.date.today()
weekday = today.strftime("%A")
start = weekday_to_num[weekday]
next_day = ((start + increment) % 7)
print(num_to_weekday[next_day])
```

Since we only called the function once, we didn't need it anymore; it worked only as a tool to help us see what simplifications we could make along the way.

Comment: First of all, this is amazing. Second of all, what happened in the first block of code where you removed the if statements. I'm sorry but i just dont understand how its checking to see which date it is. You made a second dictionary?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It's essentially a "reverse dictionary" of `calendar`. You can always rewrite a bunch of if statements on the form "if x == something then return y" into a dictionary where you map `x`s to `y`s, that's why I first simplified the if statements so it was clear that we could do this transformation.

Comment: I edited the last piece of code to make it clearer that `weekday_to_num` is exactly the reverse of `num_to_weekday` (a.k.a. `calendar`)

Comment: Wait, so you input your increment and then it converts today's date into a number based off of `weekday_to_num` which is the reverse? Right? Then it gets used in the formula and put into `next_day` and then you convert that number back into a weekday with the normal dictionary?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly correct \o. Basically your problem was going from names of weekdays to numbers, doing something on the numbers, and then going back to a weekday name; to do this weekday -> number and then number -> weekday mapping, I used two dictionaries.